# Canvas drawImage extremely slow with large world

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm working on a game that uses the canvas to draw players and the background.
Rendering players is fine however rendering the background takes a huge performance hit.

I have a camera object that properly pans my large gameArea however stalls on the background drawing.

Current Approach:

- Generate Background image once (use the worldWidth and worldHeight)
- Keep track of image
- Draw portions of the image repeatedly (slicing the image dependant on camera position's x and y)

The issue is that my worldWidth and worldHeight are pretty large e.g (10,000 x 10,000) and this is causing huge performance issues. Especially in the initial draw and subsequent renders

Code: Simplified version of my game code but still produces same problem.

```
function Canvas(width, height, camera) {
  this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  this.canvas.width = width 
  this.canvas.height = height
  this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d')
  this.camera = camera
  this.image = undefined
  document.body.appendChild(this.canvas)
}

Canvas.prototype.generateBackground = function(worldWidth, worldHeight) {
  let cvs = document.createElement('canvas')
  let ctx = cvs.getContext('2d')
  cvs.width = worldWidth 
  cvs.height = worldHeight
  let boxSize = 50
  for(let i = 0; i <= worldWidth; i += boxSize) {
    ctx.moveTo(i, 0)
    ctx.lineTo(i, worldHeight)
    ctx.stroke()
  }
  for(let j = 0; j <= worldHeight; j+= boxSize) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, j)
    ctx.lineTo(worldWidth, j)
    ctx.stroke()
  }
  let dataUrl = ctx.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");  
  let img = new Image()
  img.src = dataUrl
  this.img = img
  ctx = null
}

Canvas.prototype.drawBackground = function() {
  let canvas = this.canvas 
  let context = this.context
  let xPos = this.camera.xPos 
  let yPos = this.camera.yPos
  let img = this.img
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  context.drawImage(img, xPos, yPos, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
}


let c = new Canvas(500, 500, {xPos: 0, yPos: 0})
c.generateBackground(10000, 10000)
setInterval(() => c.drawBackground(), 15)
```

Is there a more efficient way to create the grid background and pan it according to the camera xPos and yPos?

Here is the link to the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j2yg31oj/2/). If you change the worldWidth and worldHeight back to 10,000 it crashes.

Comment: LOL 10000 * 10000 * 4 = 0.4G RAM to store the image. Simple solution. Make the image smaller!!! General rule of thumb is not to have images more than 4 times the max screen resolution (for realtime games). If you need that size then cut it up into screen sized parts, but you will get a small lag as you view new parts and have scaled down versions if you are zooming out.

Comment: Is tiling appropriate here? So use two canvas images and move them on the stage as the camera pans, relocating the images and drawing the appropriate tile as the pan progresses. [This detailed 5 part tutorial on game building](http://blog.sklambert.com/html5-canvas-game-panning-a-background/) with HTML5 canvas & JS explains this with a vertical panning background example.

Comment: I'll check out that tutorial. Thanks